# How to display blogger posts as a grid?

Tags: blogger

I have seen many themes that show the blogger posts on the blog home page as grids.

Searching on Google, I couldn't find a way to do this myself.

I want to edit the HTML code to get a grid view on my home page.

Is there any method or tutorial anyone can tell me to make this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Go to your blogger dashboard and select the blog to which you want to apply the grid view. Then go to the template section and traverse to the dynamic views, there is a grid template, select apply to blog.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to find a template (Blogger's word for a theme) that is set up for this.

You could just work out how to do the template changes yourself - but other people have solved this before.

None of the standard Blogger-provided ones do, so you need to google for others.    (But be aware that there is no guarantee that they will continue working, if Blogger change something about how their blogs operate).